# How to execute Selenium scripts on already opened browser in Mac OS

Tags: selenium

//cd /Applications

//Google\ Chrome.app --remote-debugging-port=6655 --user-data-dir=/Users/admin/Documents/chromedata

These above commands are not working when entered in terminal
getting error as-- Google Chrome.app not found

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the work done in C#.

First of all, in order to attach to an already existing Chrome session, you have to launch Chrome with some parameters, for example:

```
chrome.exe https://www.youtube.com --new-window --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

The most important thing is to specify the remote debugging port.
After that, you have to create a new istance of ChromeDriver passing the localhost IP and the remote debugging port specified above to chrome.

I don't know what language you have to write... so I'm doing it in C#.

```
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
option.DebuggerAddress = "127.0.0.1:9222";

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
```

After that, you can do the work as always.